# onChange In SelectField Component For Material-UI / React is not accepting onChange from parent Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So my workplace is using a SelectField inside of a component which is used in multiple places. Makes sense. Now When I use that component inside the current one I am working on. The onChange event which I have created does not pass the values needed to complete properly. Now if I change the SelectField to onChange={onChange} it works fine. However, it cannot be set this way as it other parts inside app are dependent on it. I am new to React. Here is my function

```
  addHistory = (field) => (event, index, value, target) => {
    const { history } = this.state;
    console.log(this.state.history);
    console.log(field);
    if (field === 'employerName' || field === 'description') {
      history[field] = event.target.value;
    } else if (field === 'roles') {
      history[field] = value;
    } else {
      history[field] = event.value;
    }
    this.setState({
      history: this.state.history,
    });
  }
```

Here is the CompanySelectField I am importing and using with component

```
  <CompanySelectField
    label={translations.translate('driverProperties', 'typeOfVehicle')}
    hint={translations.translate('driverProfile', 'pleaseSelectRole')}
    style={{ marginTop: '25px' }}
    name={'roles'}
    value={this.state.history.roles}
    onChange={this.addHistory('roles')}
    fullWidth
    required
   >
```

Here is the CompanySelectField itself

```
 <SelectField
   name={name}
   maxHeight={300}
   value={value}
   onChange={(event, index, response) => onChange(response)}
   disabled={disabled}
   hintText={hint}
  >
```

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: If i understood you correctly then changing SelectField's onChange prop like this should solve your problem => onChange={(event, index, response) => onChange(event, index, response)}

Comment: Perfect, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method which you are returning from addHistory is having 4 arguments i.e. `event, index, value, target` whereas the one you are calling from SelectField component i.e. `onChange={(event, index, response) => onChange(response)}` it is having only one argument and that too response which does not match with first argument of the above mentioned returned method.

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense and I feel stupid for not picking up on that. Thank you for answering.

Comment: No probs...pleasure was mine